# Data from csv file won't show up when called in list on Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm learning to import data from csv files to my swift project.
I'm trying to see everything is imported correctly by displaying some of the items in a list. However, even though I'm getting no errors at all, the list doesn't show up.
Can anyone help me out?

My csv setup code:

```
import Foundation

struct Leden: Identifiable {
    var voorNaam: String = ""
    var achterNaam: String = ""
    var functie: String = ""
    var id = UUID()
    
    init (raw: [String]) {
        voorNaam = raw[0]
        achterNaam = raw[1]
        functie = raw[2]
    }
}

func loadCSV(from csvName: String) -> [Leden] {
    var csvToStruct = [Leden]()
    
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: csvName, ofType: "csv") else {
        return[]
    }
    
    var data = ""
    do {
        data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return[]
    }
    
    var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    
    let columnCount = rows.first?.components(separatedBy: ",").count
    rows.removeFirst()
    
    for row in rows {
        let csvColumns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
        if csvColumns.count == columnCount {
            let ledenStruct = Leden.init(raw: csvColumns)
            csvToStruct.append(ledenStruct)
        }
    }

    return csvToStruct
}
```

My code to make the csv items appear in a list:

```
struct PraesidiumView: View {
    var individu = loadCSV(from: "Ledenlijst")
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List(individu){Leden in
            Text(Leden.voorNaam)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Praesidium")
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you check you are getting the expected data in `loadCSV` by adding 
`print("---> csvToStruct: \(csvToStruct)")` just before `return csvToStruct` .
Also I suggest using the lowercase `leden` in `List(individu) { leden in ...}`

Comment: How can I log the outcome?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the String that you are trying to parse. Btw if your file is included in your bundle no need to use guard. A crash is desired on those situations instead of failing silently.

Comment: the contents of the string I'm trying to parse? For the example I've posted it is just a list of first names

Comment: You should follow workingdog and Leo Dabus' suggestions. The first insures that you have actually decoded your csv file properly, and the second insures that you properly formatted the csv file in the first place. We can't help if we don't have all the information.

Comment: have you added the print() like I asked you to do? Can you show us what it printed? (in the Xcode console)

Comment: I'm sorry I respond now 8 hours later but I fell asleep
Here's a picture of the console:
https://imgur.com/Ic3Ve7E

Comment: So when I look at the console, it returns empty brackets. So probably the data from the csv file isn't correctly imported so I have to take a look at my import code

Comment: yes exactly, now you are awake.

Comment: Btw, I was thinking that there could be something wrong with my csv file because the rows are seperated by a lot of commas.
https://imgur.com/SK4o7yf

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this way, you also learn mvvm way.

```
class PraesidiumViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Public var ledens: [Leden] = []
    
    func loadCSV() {
        // ...
        self.ledens = csvToStruct
    }
}
```

```
struct PraesidiumView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = PraesidiumViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.ledens){ leden in
                Text(leden.voorNaam)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Praesidium")
        }.onAppear() {
            viewModel.loadCSV()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what file should I implement this? In my import file or contentview?

Comment: You can create new file and put your load csv logic code + view model in there, separate it from your view. But actually you can also write in only one file.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this (untested) to read your csv data:

```
func loadCSV(from csvName: String) -> [Leden] {
    var csvToStruct = [Leden]()
    
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: csvName, ofType: "csv") else {
        return[]
    }
    
    var data = ""
    do {
        data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return []
    }
    
    var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    
    if let firstRow = rows.first {
        rows.removeFirst()
        for row in rows {
            let csvColumns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            if csvColumns.count >= 3 {
                let ledenCol = Array(csvColumns[0..<3])
                let ledenStruct = Leden(raw: ledenCol)
                csvToStruct.append(ledenStruct)
            }
        }
    }
    return csvToStruct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I find a solution.
I just restarted following the tutorial and this time, I gave all parameters the exact same name as they did in the tutorial and that worked.

So I just messed up because of probably a wrong name assigned to a certain parameter.